# bazel build gives "Argument list too long" error

Tags: go, bazel, build-tools

Trying to build go application using bazel. It fails due to multiple packages and source files present within the application.

- OS: Mac OS (High Sierra)
- Bazel version : 0.11.1 (homebrew)
- Go rules: 0.11.0

Defined local_repository in WORKSPACE to get external dependencies

Running following command

```
bazel build //go-app
```

leads to error

> Action failed to execute: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
> "/usr/bin/sandbox-exec" (in directory
> "/TEMP_DIR/PATH"):
> error=7, Argument list too long
>
> Target //go-app:go-app failed to build

I came across https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/Args.html#use_param_file and thought it would fix my issue. Could anyone point me in the direction of how and where to implement this in my BUILD file and make it work? Thanks.

Comment: As Ittai suggested below, please do file an issue on github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go. It's likely this will need to be fixed on the rules_go side, but it would be helpful to know more about your setup (OS, bazel version, rules_go version, number of files and dependencies involved).

Comment: @JayConrod Updated the question with OS, bazel and go rules versions. Hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not in your BUILD file but rather in rules_go.
I'd recommend opening them an issue since AFAIK this is something the rule implementation needs to support.
For example in rules_scala we write the arguments to a file and then pass that file to the worker exactly like how you mention above.
https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala/blob/master/scala/private/rule_impls.bzl#L274